# Create an e-office using sharepoint site

Tags: workflow, office

I'm new to sharepoint and want to create an e-office for my organization. I want the manager can create works and assign the works to specific employees and they can do works and then write a report about it. Even they can attach documents.
Can anyone suggest me a way or book or resource to learn how to create an e-office using Sharepoint?
And an important question: Is Sharepoint the right tool for this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust me SharePoint is the best tool for this goal. You just need some basic knowledge on SharePoint Lists - specifically SharePoint Task. [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/overview-track-project-work-using-sharepoint-project-tasks-lists-HA101793879.aspx) is a basic article on task list which may help you. Feel free to ask more specific question at any point of time.